# RuntimeException and Exception Behavior

Tags: java, jvm

My question is why a `RuntimeException` is thrown by the JVM during the execution unlike 
the `Exception`   , which is thrown at compile time, even if `RuntimeException` `extends Exception`.

Where and how this difference of behavior defined?

Comment: This behaviour is defined in the [Java Language Specification, § 11.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html).

Comment: @RobinKrahl I think **11.1.1. The Kinds of Exceptions** has a better answer, but yours is good enough :)

Comment: "unlike the Exception , which is thrown at compile time" - No exceptions are thrown at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html) says that:-

> **11.1.1. The Kinds of Exceptions**
>
> The class RuntimeException is a direct subclass of Exception.
> RuntimeException is the superclass of all the exceptions which may be
> thrown for many reasons during expression evaluation, but from which
> recovery may still be possible.
>
> RuntimeException and all its subclasses are, collectively, the run-time exception classes.
>
> **11.3. Run-Time Handling of an Exception**
>
> When an exception is thrown (§14.18), control is transferred from the
> code that caused the exception to the nearest dynamically enclosing
> catch clause, if any, of a try statement (§14.20) that can handle the
> exception.
>
> A statement or expression is dynamically enclosed by a catch clause if
> it appears within the try block of the try statement of which the
> catch clause is a part, or if the caller of the statement or
> expression is dynamically enclosed by the catch clause.

Answer (score 1):

See the tutorial for help: [Exceptions tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)

Comment: Pretty much covers it

Comment: [Please don't post link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).